# Can I dim my LEDs even more?

Tags: pic, pwm

I have a PIC16F1828. I am using PWM in order to control brightness of bunch of LEDs. My goal is to dim those LEDs to the maximum point. Currently they are not dim enough.

System clock runs at 32Mhz.
Period register is set to 255.
The Timer prescaler associated to this PWM is set to 1.
When I set duty cycle to only 1 the LEDs still feel somewhat bright. Can I somehow decrease pulse width even more from the software?

Comment: pwm at a lower ratio.  do you know how?

Comment: "My goal is to dim those LEDs to the maximum point." you mean minimum point?

Comment: "When I set duty cycle to only 1 the LEDs still feel somewhat bright. Can I somehow decrease pulse width even more from the software?" Exactly what is your circuit?  can you change the burn resistor and/or supply voltage?

Comment: @JonRB Yes, that might be correct. Goal is to reach maximum of the minimum at which LEDs are barely emitting light.

Comment: @JonRB I cannot change any of those.

Comment: @Jasen I'm not sure how. I guess, if I had greater clock speeds, period would be larger but that is not an option. So answer is no!

Comment: you need more counts, perhaps you could dither the PWM turn it off for 1 turn and then one for the next. so you get 1:511 instead of 1:255, perhaps you can find a wider counter.

Comment: Having a quick look at the datasheet that PIC can have 10 bits of PWM resolution, check out that section of the datasheet - that'll get you a bit closer.

Comment: What is the drive topology ?

Comment: @PeterJ Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: @JonRB With drive topology you mean circuitry that utilizes PWM and acts to LEDs?

Answer (score 3):

> My goal is to dim those LEDs to the maximum point

The eye can detect a massive range of luminance (x axis) with a really moderate change of brightness (y axis): -

[image]
<sub>(source: [telescope-optics.net](http://www.telescope-optics.net/images/power_law3.PNG))</sub>

For a change in luminance of over a hundred dB the eye can still detect light. The luminance emitted is proportional to power supplied to the LED so if you can only change the duty cycle by 255:1 that's a change in power of 24 dB. To increase the range of brightness you need a much wider control of duty cycle or the ability to modulate the current taken by the LED when activated by the PWM signal.

> Can I somehow decrease pulse width even more from the software?

Nobody but you can answer this.

Comment: Andy that's a nice plot which shows all the required things...but can can u even add a link so that I can know more about it.

Comment: @Jasser this is the site it came from: http://www.telescope-optics.net/eye_intensity_response.htm

Answer (score 1):

You could use more bits in your PWM to increase the period. I don't know if your micro has a 16-bit PWM capable timer. If it does, that'll do the thing.

Otherwise, once you reach the minimum PWM value, you could skip pulses in software, ie pulse density modulation.

Another solution is to cheat, ie add a large value resistor in the source of the FET that switches the LEDs to make it switch slower. Tune it so it is fully ON when the PWM counter reaches about 5-10% of its period. The slow transistor turn-on means the current will rise slowly at the beginning of the PWM cycle, which means low PWM values will result in much lower average current than with a fast switching transistor.